# jquery won't target properly dynamically created elements on Firefox (working in IE8 and IE9)

Tags: jquery, firefox

Here's the dynamically created element:

```
$("<div><form id='frmUsers'>Enter the Users you want to select seperated by comma:<br/><textarea rows='4' cols='50' name='txtUsers' id='txtUsers' class='text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all' ></textarea></form></div>").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    minWidth: 400,
    title: 'Users Selection',
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function () {
            }
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function () {           
        }
    }
});
```

After the element is created and I'm successfully selecting it it's value remains empty.
I can set it (though it wont show on the page) but the input I inserted wont be reflected anywhere.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong at the OK button

Comment: Lol kayen :) @Mosh: Dynamically create a div, insert the html you want in it. Then reference it like so  "$(DivTooltipDialogObj).dialog({...."

Comment: why so unusuall syntax for making dialog in jQuery? why not <div id="dialogDiv">...</div> and in jQuery $("#dialogDiv").dialog(...)?

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen, you are right, a typo.

Comment: @jjay225 and BojanKovacevic, you are both right it should work this way, but why wouldn't it work the way I've tried it..
Never mind I'll go with your suggestion.

Thank you for your time and advice.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic: see message above.

Comment: @MosheG i am not sure why, but i think that widget needs identifier to  element (div) to work. So he can attach widget to that element. In your case, insted of identifier you just throw bunch of html code (div containing other elements inside it).